# Automatically detect whether a Haskell function is tail recursive

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I'm currently writing an auto-grader for a Haskell course. For the section on "tail-recursion", I need a way to automatically and safely detect whether a given Haskell function is tail-recursive or not.

I've searched for existing tools but couldn't find anything. I assume there must be a way to do this automatically, because after all that's what the Haskell compiler does for us. The method doesn't have to be in a specific language or anything since the grader is an external entity in the project. For example, it can be a Haskell library, a command line tool, or code written in any other language (C, Java, Python, etc).

If there actually isn't any such tools, I assume I'm gonna have to use something like a lexical analyzer for Haskell, and write custom code that detects tail recursion myself.

Comment: Just throw at it enough data to overflow the stack.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the code, and looking if the tail call optimization is done?

Answer (score 9):

I would first point out that tail recursion is rarely a virtue in Haskell. It's fine if you want to use Haskell as a medium for teaching tail recursion, but actually writing tail recursive functions in Haskell is usually misguided.

Presuming you still want to do this, I would highlight

> after all that's what the Haskell compiler does for us

Yes, indeed. So why would any tool other than the compiler exist? The compiler already does exactly this. So, when you want to do this, [use the compiler](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/extending_ghc.html#using-ghc-as-a-library). I'm sure it won't be trivial, because you'll have to learn the [compiler's types and other API](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc). But it will actually be correct.

I would start by looking at a function like [`isAlwaysTailCalled`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-9.4.4/docs/GHC-Types-Basic.html#v:isAlwaysTailCalled), and see if that does what you want. If it doesn't, maybe you need to consume the AST of the function definition.

Comment: *"actually writing tail recursive functions in Haskell is usually misguided"* Could you expand on that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann You can define `map` in a non-tail recursive fashion, `map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs`, but you can also define it using tail recursion using an accumulator parameter. The first definition also works on infinite lists, and usually leads to more efficient code: e.g. `sum (map f xs)` can run in constant space with the first definition, but requires linear space if `map` if defined using tail recursion. As a fast and loose thumb rule, if `g` returns a small-sized result like an `Int`, then tail recursion might be good, but if `g` returns a large structure (list/tree/...) not so much.

Comment: Also, I believe there was a question recently (or maybe an old question I read recently) that pointed out a tail-recursive function that was *slower* than its guarded-recursion equivalent.

Comment: @chi Thank you for answering. What you write makes sense, but without tail recursion, don't you risk exhausting the call stack?

Comment: Call stack is not a thing in Haskell

Comment: @MarkSeemann I recently wrote an answer to a different question that gave some more detail on why deep recursion doesn't cause stack consumption in Haskell, which you might be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75168800/450128

Comment: The call stack is a thing in Haskell. But it's not used in the same way as the call stack in other languages; namely: it is used to track which thunks have been entered on the way to evaluating something. A deeply-nested thunk leads to a deep stack, and you *can* blow the stack if you try to evaluate one. But tail recursion doesn't really help avoid deeply nested thunks.

Comment: In fact, I just remembered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7534489/791604), where tail recursion *caused* a stack overflow, and the fix required writing something that is technically not tail recursive.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Not in general. A non-tail call like `f x = 1 + f x` will indeed exhaust the stack, but `f x = 1 : f x` will not exhaust the stack. The point is that `a+b` needs to evaluate `a` and `b` before "returning", while `a:b` can "return" without evaluating either. In a strict language tail calls are fundamental, but in a lazy/non-strict language like Haskell using tail calls can often be severely detrimental in terms of performance.

Answer (score 7):

I basically agree with amalloy, however for this auto-grader (which presumably should only be a quick way to weed out clear-cut mistakes, not a complete reliable certification tool) I would just cobble something together in Template Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase      #-}

module TailRecCheck where

import Language.Haskell.TH

isTailRecursive :: Dec -> Bool
isTailRecursive (FunD fName clauses) = all isClauseTR clauses
 where 
       isClauseTR (Clause _ (NormalB (AppE f x)) _)
          -- Function application that could be a tail call
          = case f of
             -- It's only a tail call if the function is the
             -- one we're currently defining, and if the rest
             -- is not recursive
             VarE fn -> fn==fName && isConstant x
       -- Constant expressions are allowed as base cases
       isClauseTR (Clause _ (NormalB body) _) = isConstant body
       --isClauseTR _ ... _ = ...

       isConstant (VarE n) = n /= fName
       isConstant (ConE _) = True
       isConstant (LitE _) = True
       isConstant (AppE f x) = isConstant f && isConstant x
       isConstant (InfixE l op r)
          = all isConstant l && isConstant op && all isConstant r
       --isConstant ... = ...

assertTailRecursiveDefs :: Q [Dec] -> Q [Dec]
assertTailRecursiveDefs n = n >>= mapM`id`\case
   dec
     | isTailRecursive dec -> return dec
     | otherwise -> fail ("Function "++showName dec
                              ++" is not tail recursive.")
 where showName (FunD n _) = show n
```

To be used like

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module TailRecCheckExample where

import TailRecCheck

assertTailRecursiveDefs [d|
    f x = 4

    g 0 = 1
    g x = g (x-1)

    h 0 = 1
    h x = 1 + h (x-1)
  |]
```

```
TailRecCheckExample.hs:7:1: error:
    Function h_6989586621679042356 is not tail recursive.
  |
7 | assertTailRecursiveDefs [d|
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```